# query behaves differently on greater than equal and less than equal

Tags: sql, database

I have one record in database which has date in it as March 31, 2015. If I use `startdate:>="2015-03-01" AND startdate:<="2015-03-31"` then I get no result but if I use `startdate:>="2015-03-01" AND startdate:<"2015-04-01"` then I get expected result. Isn’t `startdate:<="2015-03-31"` and `startdate:<"2015-04-01"` are pretty much the same? Please advise.

Comment: Not if you have time in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the data type. If you are using for example SQL Server and you are using data type `datetime`, then you have both date and time. So `2015-03-31` means `2015-03-31 00:00:00` and `2015-04-01` means `2015-04-01 00:00:00`, so you get one missing day.

On the other hand these 2 conditions would be ALMOST identical:

```
startdate:<"2015-04-01"
startdate:<="2015-03-31 23:59:59"
```